# Is it possible to host only subdomain on cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I want to host only a subdomain to cloudflare. I do not want to change the nameserver of my main domain to theirs. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is possible, however it needs to be set-up via a CloudFlare Partner or you need to be on the Business or Enterprise plan. They can set-up domains via a CNAME record instead of moving nameservers.

There is a complete list of partners at: https://www.cloudflare.com/hosting-partners

We use this at [Creare](https://www.creare.co.uk), it allows us to set-up a clients site on CloudFlare yielding the performance and security benefits without altering their nameservers (where it is impractical or the client doesn't want us to), we provide this option without them needing a Business or Enterprise plan leading to it being at a lower price for the client.